# I have a Jquery sibling,parent,closest hierarchy problem

Tags: jquery

I need to add css to a sibling select element of a span element only if the span element has content.

The html is this:

```
<td class="ruleField">
   <select name="rules[field][]" class="form-select " >
      <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="554">Identifier</option>
      <option value="548">Display Name</option>
   </select>
   <span class="rules-error">Not allowed.</span>
</td>
```

This works:

```
if( $('.rules-error').text().length>0){
   $('.rules-error').siblings().css('background-color','green')
}
```

but i need it to be specific to that spans sibling select.

But this does not work:

```
if( $('.rules-error').text().length>0){
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color','green')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue in your code is that `$(".rules-error").text()` *combines* all the text from *all* the `.rules-error` elements into a single string, so if one has an error, then your code treats it as all have errors.

Clearest option is to loop through each `.rules-error` and check, which gives you the context in `this` (code already provided in another answer).

You can make this more succinct by using `.filter`.  If your rules-error spans are always blank, you could use:

```
$(".rules-error:not(:empty)").siblings().addClass("error")
```

but whitespace counts as being not-empty, so this will fail for `<span> </span>` (or a newline if you're html is formatted as such) - so you need to trim this in the filter.

```
$(".rules-error")
    .filter((_,e) => $(e).html().trim() !== "")
    .siblings()
    .addClass("error")
```

Note: this is essentially the same as looping, it just pre-loops and the applies the css to all the matching elements at once.    I also suggest adding a class for the style rather than using `.css()` as it will be easier to simply remove the class when you want to clear the errors.

Updated snippet:

```js
//$(".rules-error:not(:empty)").siblings().addClass("error")
$(".rules-error").filter((_,e) => $(e).html().trim() !== "").siblings().addClass("error")
```

```css
.error { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ruleField">
      <select name="rules[field][]" class="form-select ">
        <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="554">Identifier</option>
        <option value="548">Display Name</option>
      </select>
      <span class="rules-error">Not allowed.</span>
    </td>
    <td class="ruleField">
      <select name="rules[field][]" class="form-select ">
        <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="554">Identifier</option>
        <option value="548">Display Name</option>
      </select>
      <span class="rules-error">   </span>
    </td>
    <td class="ruleField">
      <select name="rules[field][]" class="form-select ">
        <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="554">Identifier</option>
        <option value="548">Display Name</option>
      </select>
      <span class="rules-error"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to see what code is around your if statement, but in the case of your last code, `this` does not refer to your `.role-error` element, so you can do something like this:

```
$('.rules-error').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', 'green')
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.rules-error').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', 'green')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="ruleField">
  <select name="rules[field][]" class="form-select ">
    <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="554">Identifier</option>
    <option value="548">Display Name</option>
  </select>
  <span class="rules-error">Not allowed.</span>
</td>
```

Comment: The code is actually just in a jQuery doc load. I will give that a try. Thx